# Kernel crash with KeySelect and repeated keys on list of rules

Tags: bugs, filtering, associations, crash

After running

```
KeySelect[{"a" -> 0, "a" -> 1}, True &]
```

my kernel either hangs forever (possibly with the eventual warning that "the kernel is not responding to a Dynamic evaluation") or crashes on the next evaluation. Please confirm.

Strangely enough, it only seems to crash when the above line is the last command submitted to the kernel. Evaluating the following seems fine:

```
KeySelect[{"a" -> 0, "a" -> 1}, True &]
0
```

(That is, evaluating the expression that makes it crash, then the expression 0 which evaluates fine in a single Frontend -> Kernel roundtrip seems to catch the crash.)

Context:

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"
> ```

Notebook demonstration

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8QfIyUuQqveXM1SGtvX3F6VDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: running `Association` on the input first fixes the problem.

Comment: The documentation for [`KeySelect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeySelect.html) states that it operates on an `Association` not a list of rules.

Comment: @Edmund - in all the versions I have installed, it says "KeySelect can be applied not only to Association objects, but also to lists of rules."  This is a bug, but for me it seems to be fixed.  I get the wrong behavior in version 10.3.1 but not 11.1.1

Comment: @masterxilo - your two examples seem identical...

Comment: @JasonB. fixed.

Comment: I see no crash in 11.0.1 or 11.2.1. I had to delete 11.1.1 due to low disk space.

Comment: In MMA everything is an expression. Running something with possibly invalid output should not crash the kernel (barring edge cases that eat up all your memory, etc). I see no reason to close this question.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP It appears to me that people just cannot reproduce the crash? That "everything is an expression" does not have much to do with this... `Quit[]` is legitimate, as is running (if it where available) `TerminateProcessByName@"WolframKernel.exe"`

Comment: @masterxilo well of course those fall under the edge cases. But otherwise it isn't clear that the issue affects only OP from the appearance of the question in the review queue.